# How to completely stop atop from creating logs for good?

Tags: atop

I've installed `atop` on a orangePi/RaspberryPi with only 40MB for `/var/log`.

It quickly filled my partition to 100%, I then purged it `apt purge atop` to remove it and its configuration files.

- `atop` binary doesn't exist
- its file in `/etc/init.d` doesn't exist
- no systemd service called `atop`

Nevertheless, after a reboot, the `/var/log/atop` folder comes back full with the old atop files.

- **How can I completely remove it for good?**

Edit:

```
$ ls /var/log/atop/
atop_20200822  atop_20200826  atop_20200830  atop_20200903  atop_20200907  atop_20200911  atop_20200915  atop_20200919
atop_20200823  atop_20200827  atop_20200831  atop_20200904  atop_20200908  atop_20200912  atop_20200916  atop_20200920
atop_20200824  atop_20200828  atop_20200901  atop_20200905  atop_20200909  atop_20200913  atop_20200917  atop_20200921
atop_20200825  atop_20200829  atop_20200902  atop_20200906  atop_20200910  atop_20200914  atop_20200918  atop_20200922
```

I removed atop on `2020/09/22`, the last file. And it regenerates the same folder with the same files again and again after each reboot.

#### atop folders and files:

```
# find . -type d -name  *atop*
./usr/share/doc/libatopology2
./var/log.hdd/atop
./var/log/atop
./var/cache/atop.d

# find . -type f -name  *atop*
./usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatopology.so.2.0.0
./var/log.hdd/atop/atop_20200913
...
./var/log.hdd/atop/atop_20200906
./var/log/atop/atop_20200830
...
./var/log/atop/atop_20200826
./var/cache/atop.d/atop.acct
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libatopology2:armhf.symbols
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libatopology2:armhf.md5sums
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libatopology2:armhf.list
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libatopology2:armhf.triggers
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libatopology2:armhf.shlibs
```

Comment: The files in there are usually called atop_YYYYMMDD. What dates are in use?

Comment: Old dates from 20200822 to 20200922. I `apt purged atop` on 09/22. It regenerates the old logs at each reboot...

Comment: So no new logs being generated which is good. Does `/etc/atop` still exist?

Comment: yes, sorry I could have said that in my question. `/etc/atop` doesn't exist

Comment: I found the problem... The OrangePi/RaspberryPi's ubuntu has `/var/log.hdd`, I deleted the atop folder and now it's fine. It seems `/var/log` is just a logical copy of the `/var/log.hdd` at each boot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`atop` runs as a `systemd` service located in `/lib/systemd/system/atop.service`, and its executable is:
`ExecStart=/usr/share/atop/atop.daily`

This `atop.daily` wrapper file configures the logging of `atop` , as well as the specific frequency of the logrotation of corresponding log files.

To prevent `atop.service` from being ran as that service at boot you can do:

```
sudo systemctl disable atop.service
```

#### Option 2

If you really cannot find the binary for `atop` under normal means, you may check `/etc/default/atop` which is the old way it was configured.

As the last resort you can run:

```
sudo grep -ral atop /etc/*
```

And look in the corresponding files

Comment: As said in my post: `Unit atop.service could not be found.` and `cat: /usr/share/atop/atop.daily: No such file or directory`.

Comment: no atop file under `/lib/systemd/system/` nor `/etc/systemd/system`.

Comment: just added option 2

Comment: thanks but no file/folder named **atop** under `/etc/default/` and the grep command returns only `/etc/ld.so.cache` and `grep: /etc/motd: No such file or directory`

Comment: can you run `journalctrl -r -g atop` and see if there is any mention of it.

Comment: It shows only just the commands I just tried from your answer. `systemctl disable` and `grep -ral` and the `journalctl -r -g`

Comment: What's interesting is that `ls` tells me the atop_* files were created at midnight. `-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1.4M Oct  3 00:00 atop_20200823`

Comment: ok, that tells me its ran by CRON and not systemd give me one sec

Comment: your system is `sysvinit` so the reference to it will be in `/etc/rc.*` files. can you try `sudo grep -arHi atop /etc/rc.*'

Comment: I checked, there is no cron job for sudo and my user.

Comment: I found the problem... on embedded system such as orangePi and RaspbPi, somehow devs thought it was a good idea to make a copy of `/var/log.hdd` to `/var/log`. Thanks for your help. I'll still accept your answer because it's a good summary of all the solutions.

Comment: Good find. You should definitely include your find as an answer though. It will really help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

On embedded systems such as *OrangePi and RaspberryPi*, **Armbian** uses `log2ram` to place the logs in the ram.

- `/dev/zram0       49M  756K   45M   2% /var/log`

With `/var/log` being just a logical copy (located in ram) of the `/var/log.hdd`.

Removing any folders/files from `/var/log` removes them only from the RAM and doesn't change the files/folders written in the disk/sd card.

That is the reason why the folder was coming back after each reboot.

**Deleting the folder `/var/log.hdd/atop` solved the problem.**

You can also disable the **log2ram** service: `systemctl disable armbian-ramlog.service`